# Async drilldown for stacked column chart, running an event on drilldown highcharts javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

The issue I am having is a slow loading time with a highcharts graph.
This is because my loop gets 24 points for 18 different graphs on page load.
The graph which uses this data is drilled down into from a previous graph, as shown below.

```
//Drill down for monthly periods

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <text>
        @item.QuestionType = {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                animation: false
            },
            title: {
                text: '@item.QuestionType over the last year'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                title: {
                    text: 'Month'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Questions answered'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
            series: [
            {
                name: 'Yes',
                data: [{
                    name: 'January',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 1 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'February',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 2 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'March',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 3 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'April',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 4 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'May',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 5 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'June',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 6 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'July',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 7 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'August',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 8 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'September',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 9 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'October',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 10 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'November',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 11 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'Decemebr',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes", month = 12 }),
                },],

            }, {
                name: 'No',
                data: [{
                    name: 'January',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 1 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'February',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 2 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'March',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 3 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'April',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 4 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'May',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 5 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'June',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 6 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'July',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 7 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'August',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 8 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'September',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 9 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'October',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 10 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'November',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 11 }),
                },
                {
                    name: 'December',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetMonth", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No", month = 12 }),
                },

                ]
            }]
        };
        </text>
        }



        //Drill down for yearly periods
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <text>
        @item.QuestionType = {
        chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                animation: false
        },
        title: {
            text: '@item.Category.CategoryName'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '@item.QuestionType Over the last year'
        },
        series: [{
            name: '@item.QuestionType over the last year',
            data: [{
                name: 'Yes',
                y:@Html.Action("GetYear", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes" }),
                drilldown: @item.QuestionType,
            }, {
                name: 'No',
                y: @Html.Action("GetYear", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No" }),
                drilldown: @item.QuestionType,
            }]
        }]

    };
    </text>
        }
```

So I want to click a single drill down in my yearly graph
and load only that specific question when it drills down into my monthly graph,
instead of just loading everything on page load.

Comment: Have you seen Highcharts async drilldown demo? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/ You can call for data for drilldown at drilldown event and add series as using chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown (API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown)

Comment: @KacperMadej thank you i have seen the example. my problem with it is that its not stacking my chart for me. im using a stacked column and the event allows me to drill down into a normal column. i tried adding the
stacking:'normal'
line and adding the data in the same format as in the above question i posted.
but it still does not allow me to stack.

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?